# Symfony2 doctrine reverse engineering, can not generate code one to many

Tags: symfony, doctrine

when i tried to use symfony2 doctrine reverse engineering tools, I have a one to many relationship. for example:

```
A: id, name; B: id, a_id, name
```

so the reverse engineering tools give me something like:

```
class A{  
  private id;
  private name;
}
class B{
  private id, 
  private A a;
  private name;
}
```

but what I need is :

```
class A{
  private id;
  private Bs;
  private name;
}
```

How can I make doctrine tools generate this for me ? because the data is changing and I do not want to rewrite every time the database changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to be the bringer of bad news, but you can't. The only option is to generate the entities and then add the specifics yourself.

http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#entity-generation

> This command is not suited for constant usage. It is a little helper
>   and does not support all the mapping edge cases very well. You still
>   have to put work in your entities after using this command.

Comment: well，thanks anyway. it's really a bad news. I just think it will do like hibernate.

Comment: After some observation, i found that only one-to-many can not be generated by the tool. many-to-one and many-to-many is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should go through

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

i suggest you change the entity file and then update the database.

Comment: you know sometimes this is impossible if you have 150 tables in your database .

Comment: Why does the number of tables matter?  You change an entity then "php console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql".  The only time it really becomes a problem is if you have someone else responsible for updating the database.